# How to handle columns get using inner join query

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, multiple-columns

I want to handle the column get from another table using inner join in may same entity class

My entity class

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="EMP")
public class Employee{
    @Id
    @Column(name="EmpId",length = 2, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long EmpId;

    @Column(name="EmpName", nullable = false)
    private Long EmpName;

    @Column(name="EmpSalary", nullable = false)
    private Long EmpSalary;
    
    @Column(name="EmpPf", nullable = true)
    private Long EmpPf;

    /*also have getter setter*/
}
```

```java
@Table(name="EMPPF")
public class Employee{
    @Id
    @Column(name="EmpPfId",length = 2, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long EmpPfId;

    @Column(name="EmpPfInfo", nullable = false)
    private Long EmpPfInfo;

    @Column(name="EmpPfAmount", nullable = false)
    private Long EmpPfAmount;
    
    @Column(name="EmpId", nullable = true)
    private Long EmpId;

    /*also have getter setter*/
}
```

My query is

```sql
select e.name,e.salary,ep.EmpPfInfo as EmpPf from EMP e inner join EMPPF ep on e.EmpId = ep.EmpId
```

How can I map EmpPf column in my Employee entity class so that I will not get any error if I run a simple query on "emp" table?

Answer (score 0):

You can write it with [@SecondaryTable](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-custom-crud-secondary-table-example) feature:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMP")
@SecondaryTable(name = "EMPPF", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "EmpId"))
public class Employee{
    @Id
    @Column(name="EmpId",length = 2, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long EmpId;

    @Column(name="EmpName", nullable = false)
    private Long EmpName;

    @Column(name="EmpSalary", nullable = false)
    private Long EmpSalary;
    
    @Column(name="EmpPfInfo", table = "EMPPF")
    private Long EmpPf;

    /*also have getter setter*/
}
```